# how does Java's most specific method rule for overloaded methods work with multiple parameters?

Tags: java, overloading, compile-time

Consider the following code:

```
class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 t1 = new Test1();
        Test2 t2 = new Test2();
        Test3 t3 = new Test3();
        
        Object o = "";
        String s = "";
        
        t2.method1(t2, o); // calls method1 on Test1
        t2.method1(t3, s); // compile error: reference to method1 is ambiguous
    }
}

class Test1 {
    public void method1(Test2 v1, Object o) {
        System.out.println("Test1 called");
    }
}

class Test2 extends Test1 {
    public void method1(Test1 v1, String o) {
        System.out.println("Test2 called");
    }
}

class Test3 extends Test2 {
}
```

I essentially have a `Test1` class which has subclass `Test2` which has subclass `Test3`.
I just learned that to deal with overloaded methods which have arguments that are related to each other through some is-a relationship, java picks the *most specific* method.
I wanted to test how this worked when there are multiple parameters.

The first call resolves to `Test1`'s implementation, which makes sense: Object is not a String, so `method1(Test1 v1, String o)` in `Test2` isn't a match.

But for the second call, shouldn't the `t2.method1(t3, s)` just resolve to `method1(Test2 v1, Object o)`, as that is the most "specific": `Test3` is 1 class away from `Test2` and `String` is 1 class away from `Object`?

Instead the the compiler returns `reference to method1 is ambiguous`.

How does Java deal with such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual call is

```
 method1(Test3, String)
```

The applicable methods, on a Test2 object reference, are

```
 method1(Test1, String)   // A
 method1(Test2, Object)   // B
```

For the first argument, type Test2, B is preferred - Test2 is more specific than Test1.

For the second argument, type String, A is preferred - String is more specific than Object.

Thus neither A or B is unambiguously selected. Resolution requires a target method that is the most specific for every actual argument.

[Java Language Supplement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [section 15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) for how all of this works.

In this scenario, since the methods are not generic, there are no functional interfaces involved, you can ignore a lot of the sentences. For simple cases like this, the condition for one method `m1` to be more specific than another method `m2` just boils down to:

(second bullet point of that section)

> `m2` is not generic, and `m1` and `m2` are applicable by strict or loose invocation, and where `m1` has formal parameter types `S1`, ..., `Sn` and `m2` has formal parameter types `T1`, ..., `Tn`, the type `Si` is more specific than `Ti` for argument `ei` for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n, n = k).

That is to say, the types of *every* parameter in `m1` has to be more specific than the corresponding parameter type in `m2`.

For a type to be more specific than another type, Java only looks at whether there *is* a subtype relationship. "How far away" it is does not matter.

> A type S is more specific than a type T for any expression if S <: T

Now you should see that `method1(Test1, String)` is not more specific than `method1(Test2, Object)`, because `Test1` is not more specific than `Test2`.

`method1(Test2, Object)` is not more specific than `method1(Test1, String)` either, because `Object` is not more specific than `String`.

Then the spec goes on to say:

> A method is said to be maximally specific for a method invocation if it is accessible and applicable and there is no other method that is accessible and applicable that is strictly more specific.
>
> If there is exactly one maximally specific method, then that method is in fact the most specific method; it is necessarily more specific than any other accessible method that is applicable.

Both overloads are maximally specific in this case. Some maximally specific methods are preferred if they meet some criteria (specified further down), but for simple cases like this, they don't apply.

Therefore, the compiler can't choose between the two overloads, and the call is ambiguous.